# Impact of "reference level" and "RBW" on the time domain signal in spectrum analyzer?

Tags: rf

Two questions:

(1) What is the impact of "reference level" on the time-domain signal viewed on the spectrum analyzer?

*[My attempt] Mean power level of a time domain signal would move up and down on the display? However, the envelope of the time domain signal would be same. Correct?*

(1) What is the impact of "RBW" on the time domain signal viewed on the spectrum analyzer?

*[My attempt] Smoothens the fluctuations of the envelope of a time domain signal. Is that correct?*

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Last time I checked a spectrum analyser displays a spectrum and not a time domain signal.

Comment: Spectrum analyzer with "zero span" (whichever supports. e.g., from keysight/agilent), you can see the time domain signal (but I would say it is an envelope of a time domain signal)... e.g. cf. http://ewh.ieee.org/r5/denver/sscs/Presentations/2012_10_Agilent1.pdf (slide 6)

Comment: The reference level is usually only a cursor for display and math

Answer (score 1):

(1) No. Reference level is the y-axis of the spectrum display of a time domain signal. Modifying it does not change the spectral shape, it just moves the display up/down. (It also sets the input attenuation which affects the displayed noise level)

(2) No. RBW does change the spectrum display, as it is the measurement bandwidth (kind of a frequency mask) that is applied to the spectrum display.

Addition: VBW smoothens the spectrum on the display (it is kind of a display filter).

Comment: I agree that RBW improves the SNR (or change the spectrum), which is in a frequency domain. Also VBW smoothens the spectrum on the display, which is also seen in a frequency domain.

Comment: But my questions are from time domain perspective, when you have zero span per se

Comment: With zero-span, this Agilent device is just an oscilloscope. So RBW and RefLevel does not make much sense. These settings belong to frequency mode.

Comment: When in zero-span the SA is in effect a receiver at some particular frequency.  The RBW sets the IF filter bandwidth, so it acts as a low pass filter- the smaller the bandwidth the 'smoother' the time domain signal, however once your RBW is smaller than your (modulated) signal you will start to lose that information (whether that's important depends on what you are attempting to achieve with the measurement).  For CW signals if the incoming signal starts to drift out of your IF bandpass, the time domain signal will start to drop.

Comment: *With zero-span, this Agilent device is just an oscilloscope* That's not what zero span does. In normal mode, the X-axis shows frequency, that frequency is is swept (in time) to make the plot. In zero span, the the sweep is stopped at the frequency you set. Then the X-axis shows time and Y-axis power in the frequency band you set. An oscilloscope shows an unfiltered signal. A SA in zero span still filters.

Comment: I‘ll integrate @Bimpelrekkie s comment into my answer, as it makes sense to me.

Comment: Also the reference level is usually used by the SA to set the input attenuation.  If you set it too large then your signal will be attenuated and the SA's noise level will be more noticeable.